# How to use javascript reduce function for objects in an array to get string values

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have an array of objects from which  I would like to get names. I am trying to use reduce for that but the problem is that reduce returns the first values as undefined and only returns the last value in the array. I wonder why that is? How does reduce works with strings inside objects?

my code:

```
    var data = [ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]

    var result = function(){

    var names = data.reduce(function(a, b){
    return  a.name + ',' + b.name
    })
    return names

    };

    var res = result();
    console.log(res)

**`output // undefined,Maggie`**
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yo3rjuvm/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reduce executes the callback function once for each element present in
>   the array, excluding holes in the array.

First 2 arguments are :
accumulator ( in your case `a` )
currentValue ( in your case `b` )

[InitialValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters) isn't provided so reduce will execute the callback function starting at index 1, skipping the first index. First time the accumulator is the object `{name: 'Bart'}` , second time is a string `"Bart,Lisa"`

```js
  var data = [ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]

    var result = function(){

    var names = data.reduce(function(a, b){
    return  (a.name || a) + ',' + b.name
    })
    return names

    };

    var res = result();
    console.log(res)
```

For a cleaner solution you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of reduce .(Is more readable )

```js
var data = [ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]
var result = data.map(x =>x.name).join(",");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you explain why `(a.name || a)` ?

Comment: a much cleaner way would be simply to provide an initial value

Comment: i think "map" its better than"reduce" for that task

Comment: Don't use `map` when you reduce the structure of the iteratee. Besides, your `reduce` example will throw when applied to an empty array. Always use an initial value.

Answer (score 1):

like so:

```
var names = data.reduce(function (names, item) {
  return names + ' ' + item.name;
}, "");
```

or:

```
var names = data.map(function (item) { return item.name }).join(" ");
```

Comment: yep, they actually need `map` here, not `reduce`

Comment: Your `reduce` is broken if there is only one item in the list. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) takes two arguments. The first is the accumulated value and the second is one of the elements in the array. In the beginning the supplied accumulator is used, in my example an empty string. I fnot supplied it will be the null value `undefined`.

```
arrData.reduce(function (strAccumulator, objElement) {
    return (strAccumulator ? strAccumulator + ', ' : '' ) + objElement.name;
}, "");
// ==> "Bart, Lisa, Maggie"
```

If you use Underscore, you can do this cleaner with [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
_.pluck(arrData, 'name').join(', ');
// ==> "Bart, Lisa, Maggie"
```

Note that if your object has a `toString` function that returns the string representation you would like, you can omit plucking:

```
function Simpson(strName) {
  this.name = strName;
}
Simpson.prototype.toString = function(){
  return this.name;
};
var arrData = [new Simpson('Bart'), new Simpson('Lisa'), new Simpson('Maggie')];

arrData.join(', ');
// ==> "Bart, Lisa, Maggie"
```

Comment: Great answer – I particularly like the last demonstration using `toString`

Answer (score 1):

**The why and the how**

Several answers here rush to get the answer correct, but fail to build a robust, complete function. This answer is meant to be exhaustive and give you insight into *why* we would choose certain implementations over others

---

**Contract**

For your function to work on all `[{name: String}]` inputs (it *should*), you have to handle 3 cases

```
listofNames([])                                   // ''
listofNames([{name: 'Bart'}])                     // 'Bart'
listofNames([{name: 'Bart'},{name: 'Lisa'}, ...]) // 'Bart, Lisa, ...'
```

1. an empty array (`[]`) returns an empty string
2. a *single* name will just return that name – `', '` separator is not present
3. an array of *2 or more* names will return the names with separators between

---

**Fulfilling your request**

You asked to do this with `Array.prototype.reduce`, so we'll start there. What you'll notice about this answer is

- it works for all input scenarios described above, making `listOfNames` a *total function* – several other answers fail to accommodate (**1**) and (**2**) above.
- it only uses a *single* `if`, because that's all that is required – using `if` within the reducer is wasteful
  *

```js
const listOfNames = ([x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return ''
  else
    return xs.reduce((acc, {name}) => acc + ', ' + name, x.name)
}

console.log(listOfNames([]))                                // ''
console.log(listOfNames([{name: 'Bart'}]))                  // 'Bart'
console.log(listOfNames([{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}]))  // 'Bart, Lisa'
```

---

**A recommendation**

You tagged this question with <kbd>functional-programming</kbd> so we're going to look at this from another perspective. What we did above was *re-invent* the `Array.prototype.join` function – only ours is actually a little *worse*.

```js
console.log([].join(', '))               // ''
console.log(['Bart'].join(', '))         // 'Bart'
console.log(['Bart','Lisa'].join(', '))  // 'Bart, Lisa'
```

Our function is more specific and does not allow us to change the separator that is used (always uses `', '`) and it assumes each element in the array has a `name` property.

In functional programming paradise kingdom, we should be making our functions as **generic** as possible - this allows for the most code recycling.

OK, so instead of reinventing a perfectly good function, we just need to convert our array of *objects* into an array of *names*, then use the perfectly good `join` function

```js
const prop = x => y => y[x]

const listOfNames = xs =>
  xs.map(prop('name')).join(', ')

console.log(listOfNames([]))                                // ''
console.log(listOfNames([{name: 'Bart'}]))                  // 'Bart'
console.log(listOfNames([{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}]))  // 'Bart, Lisa'
```

---

***"But that's basically the same thing some other people said"***

Yep, but clearly they don't realize *why* it's better. They think because the resulting code is shorter, it's somehow better - otherwise, they wouldn't have also given `reduce` solutions that are so horribly complex/incomplete.

Now you know *why* certain solutions are better than others, and you can evaluate which one is best for you

**Quiz:** can you name one reason why the `map`+`join` solution *could* be worse than our custom `reduce` solution?

Comment: thankyou for a great answer can you right your solutions in vanilla JavaScript so that I can understand it better.  I do not understand what exactly const prop = x => y => y[x] is doing

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the previous value (a) is set. if not return the current value (b). Also pass in an empty string as the initial value for the reduce function.

```
var data = [ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ]

var result = function(){
    var names = data.reduce(function(a, b){
        return  a ? a + ',' + b.name : b.name;
    },"");
    return names;
};
var res = result();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You re-invented a bad version of `Array.prototype.join`

Comment: sure you could also use map and join but the question was why the first value of the reduce output is undefined.

Comment: and regarding to your quiz, if performance is crucial reduce is around 3 times faster.